# Want to setup setting data in Windows Azure Stream Analytics

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics

Need help to setup the Reference data in stream analytics. I want to add setting(default) data of my application into stream analytics. I can add the reference data and by doing upload sample file I can upload JSON or CSV file. However while firing a join query it gives 0 rows as all reference data haven't stored (So null if left outer join).

I investigate the issue and I think it is due to Path Pattern, but I do not have much idea about it.

Comment: Have you placed reference data in a blob store and configured it as an iinput? It is not possible to assist you without understanding exactly how your inputs, outputs and query are configured.

Comment: Yes, I had, I found the issue, it was not proper JSON file. Thanks for your time and comment Pete M.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, as you said, you had been sure that the issue was caused by `Path Pattern`/`Path Prefix Pattern`, but I could not give some helpful suggestion for you without any details, such as the screenshot of your `Path Pattern` setting.

So just list some resources as references for you, hope these help for resolving your issue.

1. Two screenshots about `Path Prefix Pattern`/`Path Pattern` which be introduced from Link [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-define-inputs#create-a-blob-storage-data-stream-input) & [2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-use-reference-data#configuring-reference-data).

[image]

[image]

2. A sample [Use Stream Analytics to process exported data from Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-export-stream-analytics) introduce how to read stream data from Blob Storage at its section [Create an Azure Stream Analytics instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-export-stream-analytics#create-an-azure-stream-analytics-instance), which step as similar as for `Reference data`.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was due to not properly formatted JSON file.